# How can I make a pom.xml use local properties specific to each developer's local environment?

Tags: maven

We have a maven project on our subversion server. There is a `pom.xml` inside the project. When I want to import project to my local computer and make my changes on it, I have to change this lines relative to my local system inside the `pom.xml` because I need to deploy project on my local system to test it before submit:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
            <webappDirectory>/opt/JBoss_4.0.4.GA/server/default/deploy/agg-gateway.war</webappDirectory>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Each of my team members should do that relative to their local systems.

But this settings must be unchanged on main project an I have not to submit `pom.xml` to subversion. If one of my team members changes this file, every time I update the project, I have to change it again relative to my local system.

Is there any way to make a file unchangeable on subversion? I can not control everybody to not to submit `pom.xml` to `svn`.

Comment: Surely, this is really a question about subversion, not maven.  So why is it tagged "maven"?

Comment: @StephenC sorry tags was incorrect. I changed them.

Comment: This has nothing to do with subversion, [this is an XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The solution is in my answer. **Use maven correctly, it supports what you want to do directoy!**, trying to control this with subversion is a path to madness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### [Injecting POM Properties via settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/examples/injecting-properties-via-settings.html):

Use a custom property in your `~/.m2/settings.xml` which is specific to each developer:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>local-weblogic</id>
    <properties>
      <local.weblogic.deployment.directory>/opt/JBoss_4.0.4.GA/server/default/deploy/agg-gateway.war</local.weblogic.deployment.directory>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
  <activeProfile>local-weblogic</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

and use a reference to the property in your `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
            <webappDirectory>${local.weblogic.deployment.directory}</webappDirectory>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```